# Simple cache mechanism?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cache

In my system I frequently require data by Ajax requests. For example, different lists, content of modal dialogs, etc. This data can't be changed after request, so I wrote cache mechanism which stores Ajax result and then before Ajax request checks is there stored data.
Here is example:

```
YFeX.cache = { }; // YFex is my own namespace

$('#account_modal_button').click(function () {
    if (YFeX.cache.account_modal !== undefined) {
        YFeX.modal(YFeX.cache.account_modal.title, YFeX.cache.account_modal.body);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/?/login',
            dataType:'json',
            context:$(this),
            success:function (data) {
                YFeX.cache.account_modal = data.modal;
                // YFeX.modal will be called automatically
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Are there any 'bad' parts in my solution?

Comment: Not much to improve in just the couple of lines, but why not use browser's default caching?

Comment: @Juhana but Ajax request is executed in any case.

Comment: No, it isn't. That's the whole point of cache.

Comment: Doesn't [jQuery already have a cache mechanism](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for it's AJAX functions? Adding `cache : true` should cache the response internally in jQuery. True, the AJAX routine still needs to be called. But if jQuery determines that there is cached data, probably it will not make a request and the response of the call will be from the cache.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I already tried set `cache` to `true`, but Firegug shows that Ajax request still sent.

Comment: @Juhana can you give an example?

Comment: It's not enough to set `cache: true`, the server must also send the correct headers. `cache: false` makes sure the response is not cached, but `cache: true` can't override the server instructions.

Comment: @Juhana oh, thank you, now I understand how to use HTTP cache... If you want — answer my question and I will mark it is accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over;

- Unless `YFeX` is also a constructor, it should be `yFex`
- lowerCamelCase is good for you: `account_modal` -> `accountModal`
- I would store `YFeX.cache.account_modal` into a `var cachedAccountModal` so that you do not have to repeat `YFeX.cache.account_modal` all the time
- Your code is very optimistic, you should also deal with `fail`
- Consider using the shorthand `$.get()`

Other than that, the code looks fine to me.

Comment: Oh, after a year I see my own mistakes.
But anyway thank you, it maybe helpful for someone...

PS. `account_modal` means account[modal], I didn't want to create another arrays in `cache` array.